# changing font size in regression tree plot

Tags: r, visualization, rpart

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
prp(fit, type = 4, extra = 101, leaf.round = 1, fallen.leaves = TRUE,
    varlen = 0, tweak = 0.8)
```

[image]

I'm trying to get the text to fit inside the rounded squares. I tried lowering the `tweak` and `cex` values, but it appears that the rounded squares get smaller along with the text. How can I make the font size smaller?

Comment: If you just scale the image text begins to fit the boxes

Comment: @Bulat, can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, I just increased the image size and it looks ok

Comment: @Bulat, I'm using RStudio, and I've tried making the plot window bigger by just dragging the borders but it's not enough to make it look nice.

Comment: Do you intend to save it to a file? in that case you can do `post(fit, file = "tree2.ps", 
      title = "Regression Tree")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out this graphical package instead:

```
library(maptree)
draw.tree(fit,cex=3)
```

Change `cex` to get different font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same package - `rpart.plot`

`fancyRpartPlot(fit,cex=3)`

Change `cex` as better suites your case, as explained by Otto_k.

Comment: that is not the same package - that function comes from the rattle library.